# How to hide S3 bucket url when using with rails ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

How do you hide the S3 bucket url behind a custom domain like media.example.com with ActiveStorage so that when you open an ActiveStorage blob image it redirects you to a domain called media.example.com rather than bucket_name.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com.

An example would be image

> localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBZ2tCIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--e87b2ee9e5c5f3ec8913c7c514b755f8cc769127/serial_number_photo__cam_1678996646233.jpg

Redirects you through to:

> BUCKET_NAME.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/g2tt3fm9a1yvf5rdu6zrsoar5e9k?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D"serial_number_photo__cam_1678996646233.jpg"%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27serial_number_photo__cam_1678996646233.jpg&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAS3VSSD2HVNHRIAEB%2F20230428%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230428T133352Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=d4b1bb71a6a798f7cadf69d52e6ced3d15fa80df2656eac70130ec6580927d7c

What I want it to do is to redirect to:

> media.example.com/g2tt3fm9a1yvf5rdu6zrsoar5e9k?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D"serial_number_photo__cam_1678996646233.jpg"%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27serial_number_photo__cam_1678996646233.jpg&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAS3VSSD2HVNHRIAEB%2F20230428%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230428T133352Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=d4b1bb71a6a798f7cadf69d52e6ced3d15fa80df2656eac70130ec6580927d7c

2 questions:

1. How do you configure rails to rediect to that media.example.com domain?
2. How do you configure Amazon S3 to accept media.example.com/.... when media.example.com is set as a CNAME through to the bucket? (I have it currently set up and i keep getting 'AccessDenied')

Comment: I have found that if you want to use custom domains with s3 you need to employ CloudFront and set up the s3 bucket as an origin.  However, I have only done that to deploy static sites in s3 and have not tried to make that work in the context of active storage.

Comment: Check this tutoriel for the S3 permission issue: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-configure-bucket-permissions